# Bootstrap Datetimepicker - Change Popover Position

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, datetimepicker

I'm using the following Bootstrap plugin and basically would like to change the placement of the popover containing the calander / time picker to show on the left of the add-on button rather than on the right as in the plugin demo.

http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

I still need the add-on button on the right but require the popover to show to the left, beneath the input field.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is about it:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <input id="simpleInput" type="text" class="span3 datepicker" />
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="dateTest">New Date:</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <div class="input-append date datepicker">
                        <input id="compInput" class="span6" type="text" /> <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using

```
#target {
    margin: 2em;
}
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajhbg/41/)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the positioning of the Datetimepicker to the left by adding

```
pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
```

Try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#your_date_time_picker').datetimepicker({
      language: 'en',
      pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
    });
  });
```

The other positioning options are:

```
pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
pickerPosition: "top-left"
pickerPosition: "top-right"
```